# Get command input from NSTextView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextview

OK, this what I have in mind :

- I have an `NSTextView` I'm using as a "Console"/"Terminal"
- I want to be able to process user input on "enter"
- When user enters something and presses "return", I want to be able to process that input

Is there anything built-in for such a functionality? Do you know of any open-source projects / example code that make use of this feature?

Any ideas?

---

*Please do not mention **iTerm2** (unless you've got some really specific piece of code to point me to) - this thing needs either a GPS Navigator or a full month of studying it before I grasp the core points...*

Answer (score 0):

What about using [NSTask](http://cocoadev.com/wiki/NSTask)

NSTask Class gives you most of the thing, just put a string which should be a valid shell command or unix command and execute it.

See [AppleDocumentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTask_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: My question is **not** about the terminal-like function of an `NSTextView` and how to asynchronously execute commands (actually what I need for has nothing to do with "real" executable shell commands); all I'm interested in is how to intercept key events and detect when a new "command" has been entered. (Still experimenting with all sorts of workarounds : subclassing `NSTextView`, playing with Delegate methods, or whatever - but still nothing; `NSTextView` has got to be one of the most horrible Cocoa built-in controls... :S)

Comment: so u looking for a delegate kind of stuff that should get fire when text gets changed and you hit "Enter" ?

Comment: Hmmm... yep. To be honest, I've currently thought of a rather simple workaround (which still fits my goal - perhaps in an even more efficient way) : instead of having the console-like `NSTextView` read user input, I'll leave the `NSTextView` for message output and just add an `NSTextField` (much easier to play with) below it, solely for the purpose of receiving user input.